# Ui-select dropdown scroll bar height visibility

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-Select for Select and Search i need help here.please see attached image and help how can i increase the number of items visible in scroll bar of dropdown List.

```
Ui-Select
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEBlT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of the dropdown. The dropdown has a `.selectize-dropdown-content`.